# Create vertical Tab using html css

Tags: html, css

[image]

Hi,

I am designing a page with vertical tab. But I am not sure about how to achieve this design. I don't want to use any javascript, jquery etc. Planning to create separate views for each tab menu item. So i can change the active tab in each view. Please help to solve this issue. I don't have much code to post. Please provide some links to move in right direction.. Thanks in advance.

This is what i did to acheive the design

```
<style>
 #content
{
   background-color: #f2f2f2;
   padding: 20px 10px;
   overflow: auto;
}
#tab-container
{
   float: left;
   margin: 50px 0 0 0;
   width: 126px;
}
#tab-container ul
{
   list-style: none;
   text-align: center;
}
#tab-container ul li
{
   border-top: 1px solid #666;
   border-right: 1px solid #666;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
   border-left: 8px solid #666;
   background-color: #ddd;
   margin: 8px 0;
}
#tab-container ul li a,
#tab-container ul li a:visited
{
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #666;
   display: block;
   padding: 15px 5px;
}
#tab-container ul li:hover
{
   border-left: 8px solid #333;
}
#tab-container ul li a:hover
{
   color: #000;
}
#tab-container ul li.selected
{
   border-right: none;
   background-color: #fff;
   border-left: 8px solid #006699;
}
#main-container
{
   min-height: 400px;
   margin: 0 0 0 125px;
   padding: 20px;
   background-color: #fff;
   border: 1px solid #888;
}
 </style>
  <div id="content">
   <div id="tab-container">
      <ul>
         <li class="selected"><a href="">Introduction</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Html</a></li>
         <li><a href="">CSS</a></li>
         <li><a href="">JavaScript</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   <div id="main-container">
      <h1>Put your content here...</h1>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you dont know how to do it...then google it..look for templates and learn css which is close to it or else if you have tried something show us..we will correct it

Comment: You have explained with jquery example.Could you please help me using html,javascript,css (without jquery and html5).

Answer (score 17):

may i sure `below demo` useful for you;

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tj_vantoll/nn2Qw/)**

**[DEMO1](http://jsfiddle.net/frabiacca/7pM7h/5/)**

**html**

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#a">Tab A</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#b">Tab B</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#c">Tab C</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#d">Tab D</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="a">
        Content of A
    </div>
    <div id="b">
        Content of B
    </div>
    <div id="c">
        Content of C
    </div>
    <div id="d">
        Content of D
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.ui-tabs.ui-tabs-vertical {
    padding: 0;
    width: 42em;
}
.ui-tabs.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-widget-header {
    border: none;
}
.ui-tabs.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav {
    float: left;
    width: 10em;
    background: #CCC;
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
    border-right: 1px solid gray;
}
.ui-tabs.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li {
    clear: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0.2em 0;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-width: 1px 0 1px 1px;
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    right: -2px;
    z-index: 2;
}
.ui-tabs.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.6em 1em;
}
.ui-tabs.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li a:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.ui-tabs.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active {
    margin-bottom: 0.2em;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
}
.ui-tabs.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.ui-tabs.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-panel {
    float: left;
    width: 28em;
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 0;
    position: relative;
    left: -1px;
}
```

**js**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#tabs')
        .tabs()
        .addClass('ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix');

  </script>
```

Comment: I know the OP asked for links, however, unqualified links aren't very helpful. Better if you explain something of how to solve the problem.

Comment: You have explained with jquery example.Could you please help me using html,javascript,css (without jquery and html5).